# clang fails to compile simple c++ with "ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64"

Tags: macos, command-line

I cannot compile a trivial three-line C++ program with clang on MacOS Catalina. I'm using zsh and have installed the command line xcode tools.

`$ clang -o test test.cpp` produces many lines of error output, ending with

```
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation
```

Comment: Besides being probably better asked on SO the question lacks part of the relevant error output.

Answer (score 2):

`$ clang++ -o test test.cpp` works as expected, don't forget to use `clang++` for C++